# Gnome extensions reset after each reboot

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension

*Disclaimer: Ubuntu is not my main distro.*

My company manages my laptop, and every time I reboot it, all (Gnome) user extensions get disabled, and all system extensions get enabled. (One of the two system extensions is so annoying that I manually deleted it for good.)

[image: Extension Manager]

What's the difference between system extensions and user extensions specifically? Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Update: I do have root/admin privileges to tweak things.